# Emacs minor mode programming: cancel toggle-off procedure?

Tags: emacs, elisp, minor-mode

I am programming my own Emacs minor mode using the idioms and macros similar to this minimal example:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode foo-mode
  "Toggle Foo mode."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " Foo"
  :group 'foo
  (if foo-mode
      (do-enable-foo)
    (do-disable-foo))
  )

(defun do-enable-foo ()
  "Enable foo minor mode"
  (message "Enabling foo...")
  (if test-something
      (message "Foo enabled after disabling was canceled!")
    (message "Foo enabled from scratch"))
  )

(defun do-disable-foo ()
  "Disable foo minor mode"
  (message "Disabling foo...")
  (if (not certain-situation)
      (message "... done.") ; finish disabling foo
    ;; else forms:
    (message "Need to cancel disabling foo!")
    (foo-mode 1)) ; turning foo mode on again
  )
```

During the toggling off of the minor mode, a `'certain-situation` may arise when I have to cancel toggling off.  Currently, I am thinking since I am using the `define-minor-mode` macro, that I cannot bail out but just have to programmatically turn the mode on again using `(foo-mode 1)` as seen in the code.

If I go this route, I will have to handle this differently in the enabling function `do-enable-foo` -- so my first question is how to detect this case using the placeholder `'test-something` in the code above?

Or, is there a cleaner way to achieve the cancel, for example, by signaling an error instead of `(foo-mode 1)` to prevent the mode toggle from going through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Stefan's suggestion in the following way using the variable to signal to the minor mode definition that the mode was enabled as a result of cancelling the disable process (actually as a result of a user query).  I didn't dare to use the idea of simply setting the mode variable to `t` but I cannot find the documentation anymore that cautioned against it.  It might be worthwhile to see if using `(setq foo-mode t)` actually lets me eliminate the new variable `canceled-foo-off`.

```
(defvar canceled-foo-off nil "Set to `true' if user canceled toggling off foo.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'canceled-foo-off)

(define-minor-mode foo-mode
  ...
  (if foo-mode
      (if canceled-foo-off
        (setq canceled-foo-off nil) ; Mode was turned back on from cancelling 
      (do-enable-foo)) ; Mode was turned on from scratch
    (do-disable-foo))
  )

(defun do-disable-foo ()
  "Disable foo minor mode"
  (if (not certain-situation)
      ...
    ;; else forms:
    (setq canceled-foo-off t) ; make sure mode starting procedure is not run!
    (foo-mode 1)) ; turning foo mode on again
  )
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `setq` instead of `let`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cancel the "turn off", rather than call `(foo-mode 1)`, you can just `(setq foo-mode t)`.

If for some reason you really want to call `(foo-mode 1)` recursively to (re)enable the mode, then you can do it in the following way:

```
(defvar foo-mode--reenabling nil)
....
(defun do-enable-foo ()
  (if foo-mode--reenabling
      ...
    ...))
...
(defun do-disable-foo ()
  ...
  (let ((foo-mode--reenabling t))
    (foo-mode 1)))
```

Comment: I did a variation on the idea with the variable and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very scared about preventing the user from turning off a minor mode. I mean, if the minor mode is broken, or misbehaving, you leave them with with a broken Emacs that must be killed. What is the condition that you are thinking off?

The opposite situation -- a mode which refuses to be turned on under certain circumstances -- already happens -- paredit-mode is a nice example. It just throws an error in the define-minor-mode body.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but it's not an answer to the question. Please move this to a comment.